# How to overwrite a defcustom of a package within the initfile?

Tags: init-file, defcustom

I have an installed packages (say `mypackage.el`) in `\.emacs.d\lisp\` directory. In that package there is

```
(defcustom xyz "path1" "Path to the program"
  :group 'blablabla
  :type 'string)
```

I would like to change the above as

```
(defcustom xyz "path2" "Path to the program"
  :group 'blablabla
  :type 'string)
```

I prefer to do this modification not in the package el file but in my init file. However adding the above in the init file has no effect and for the package the variable `xyz` is always `path1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defcustom` (and `defvar`) are only for the library that *defines* the variable.  You don't want to copy those.

As a user, you can either use the customize interface:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `xyz` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or else you can use `setq` to set the value in your init file:

```
(setq xyz "path2")
```

As you'll have guessed from the names, the customize interface only works on `defcustom` variables (i.e. "user options").

---

> However adding the above in the init file has no effect and for the package the variable `xyz` is always `path1`.

This is intentional.  When a variable already has a value, and a `defcustom` or `defvar` for that variable is evaluated, the pre-existing value is kept.  This means that you can `(setq xyz "path2")` in your init *without* needing to first load the library which defines the variable, because if you do subsequently load (or *re*-load) that library, the default value won't clobber your custom value.

Comment: n.b. `setq` doesn't *necessarily* work with `defcustom` variables, as they might have a custom setter function which does more complex things with the value, and using `setq` would mean that the setter function was not invoked.  It *will* work in most cases, but using the customize interface is the *guaranteed* safe option.

Comment: And to do this from file, this is the command, right? `(custom-set-variables '(xyz "path2"))`?

Comment: I think `(customize-set-variable 'xyz "path2")` is preferred, with the caveat that (either way) your custom file will still be updated with that value the next time it is saved, and so there may be limited value to setting things outside of the customize UI (as you're then effectively doing it in two places).  Emacs 29 will introduce a macro (probably named `setopt`) for doing this in code *without* touching your custom file.

Comment: FYI `setopt` currently looks like this: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/cus-edit.el?id=136f1cb54962f5dcae9e8b63e41e4df70995599c#n1047